# React component errors undefined but should return null

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get this component to render and I keep getting the error `A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.` I have no idea what the problem is because I'm returning `null` if there's nothing to return.

Any thoughts?

Component: `CompanyLogo`

```
function CompanyLogo(props) {
  props.companies.map((company) => {
    if (props.companyId == company._id) {
      console.log("Test to see if firing");
      return <p>Return as a test</p>;
    }
    return null
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Maximum Number of JSX Root Nodes`](https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/maximum-number-of-jsx-root-nodes.html)

From the docs,

> Currently, in a component's render, you can only return one node; if you have, say, a list of divs to return, you must wrap your components within a div, span or any other component

```
function CompanyLogo(props) {
  props.companies.map((company) => {
    if (props.companyId == company._id) {
      console.log("Test to see if firing");
      return (<p>Return as a test</p>);
    }
    return (<p></p>)
  })
}
```

You can remove redundant return statement,

```
function CompanyLogo(props) {

    let component = <p></p>;
    props.companies.map((company) => {
        if (props.companyId == company._id) {
            console.log("Test to see if firing");
            component = <p>Return as a test</p>;
        }
    });
    return component;
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Works like a charm.

Comment: use `.some()`, not `.map`. if your match is say, logo # 2, and you have 50 more, why continue looping?

Answer (score 0):

the `CompanyLogo(props)` function doesn't return anything. It should return something, try adding `return` to the function:

```
function CompanyLogo(props) {
  let elementsArr = props.companies.map((company) => {
    if (props.companyId == company._id) {
      console.log("Test to see if firing");
      return <p>Return as a test</p>;
    }

    return null;
  });

  return (<div>{elementsArr}</div>);
}
```

You have to make sure that the mapped `props.companies` is a valid React Element though.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is you are not returning anything from `CompanyLogo` method, you are simple using return inside map function body.

Write it like this:

```
function CompanyLogo(props) {
    let result = props.companies.map((company) => {
        if (props.companyId == company._id) {
              return <p>Return as a test</p>;
        }
        return null;
    });
    return <div> {result} </div>     //add this return
}
```

Same code you can write it like this by using [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
function CompanyLogo(props) {
    let result = props.companies.map(company => props.companyId == company._id ?
            <p> Return as a test </p>
        :
            null
    });
    return <div> {result} </div>   //add this return 
}
```

**Suggestion**: `map` is helpful when we want to return something for each value, here only one company will satisfy the if condition, so in this case map is not the correct way to loop over all the companies, better to use **[Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).**